# Dynamically Building Table of Referenced Documents

Tags: macros

I have a document that's going to reference other documents. For now, I have placed placeholders to the usage throughout my document as follows:

```
... blah blah \docReferenceMeaningfulNameHere blah blah ...
```

where `MeaningfulNameHere` is some sort of internal name that I can use to keep track of the document in the `*.tex` files.

I have all of these macros defined in one spot as follows:

```
\newcommand{\docReferenceMeaningfulNameHere}{Document 1234 ("Document Title")}
\newcommand{\docReferenceMeaningfulNameHere2}{Document 1235 ("Document 2 Title")}
\newcommand{\docReferenceMeaningfulNameHere3}{Document 1236 ("Document 3 Title")}
```

This works fine, but I would like to improve this as follows:

- I want to be able to create a table of referenced documents dynamically from the macros so I don't have to repeat anything as new document references get added.
- I might want additional information in the table than what I have in the references throughout the document, e.g. Revision, Release Date.
- Ideally, I don't want to specify the full document title for each reference, perhaps at most only the first reference, but I can live with no references as long as I have the table mentioned above.

I'm flexible on changing what I currently have to accomplish the goal, and in case it matters, I'm currently using pdflatex.

I'm envisioning something like the following, but I'm not sure how to tie everything to use `#1`:

```
% #1 - meaningful name referenced in the code
% #2 - Document number
% #3 - Document title
% #4 - Document revision
% #5 - Release date
\newcommand{\docReference}[3]{Document #2 ("#3")} % TODO need help here

\newcommand{\tableOfReferencedDocuments}{
    % TODO need help here
}

% List of Document References
\docReference{MeaningfulNameHere}{1234}{Document Title}{A}{1 Jan 2019}
...

\tableOfReferencedDocuments

... blah blah \docReference{MeaningfulNameHere} blah blah ...
```

Comment: you could use bibtex and the standard `\cite` mechanism to keep track of documents that you reference. you could put all the metadata that you mention in a `bib` file.